# Centos 7 firewalld won't close a port

Tags: centos7

I opened a port for ftp but I want to close it.  I tried

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=21/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```

For the first command, I also tried 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --service=ftp --remove-port=21/tcp --permanent

But I stll get

```
  # firewall-cmd --list-all

public (active)

  target: default

  icmp-block-inversion: no

  interfaces: enp1s0

  sources: 

  services: ssh dhcpv6-client ftp

  ports: 21/tcp

  protocols: 

  masquerade: no

  forward-ports: 

  source-ports: 

  icmp-blocks: 

  rich rules:
```

===========
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
/j

Answer (score 2):

In your first firewalld command, you change the permanent configuration *and not the running configuration*.

In your second command, you then undo your change by overwriting the permanent configuration with the running configuration.

Because of this, at no time did the allowed port ever get removed from the running configuration.

You may solve this by removing the port from the running configuration, by *not* using `--permanent`, and then making it permanent with `--runtime-to-peramnent` as you had done.

Comment: Unfortunately, that comment without --permanent yields an error "option can be used only with --permanent'.  But I get what you say.  So I tried only the first and 3rd commands.   No luck though.  It says "warning: NOT_ENABLED 21:tcp", but I still get the same result from list-all and the port still works.  [I had tried a number of different ways of doing this but didn't post all of them - something else is going on?]

Comment: That should certainly work without `--permanent`. Exactly what did you attempt to run?

Answer (score -1):

Correct solution to remove the port

firewall-cmd --remove-port=21/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload

ftp is a built-in service so can't remove it.